Non-orientable surface with constant Gaussian curvature and automorphism group $G$
Given a finite group $G$, does there exist a non-orientable, closed surface with constant Gaussian curvature such that the automorphism group of the surface is $G$?  I know this statement is true for orientable surfaces, but was wondering if it generalizes for non-orientable surfaces as well.
The motivation is I'm trying to create strategy game maps that are highly symmetric so that they can be played by multiple people simultaneously.  For example, if the map of the strategy game was the flat torus whose fundamental polygon is the rhombus with angles of 60 degrees and 120 degrees, then 7 people could vs each other simultaneously.
In the image above, imagine each player's base is located at the center of one of the 7 colored bases.  This setup would have 84 automorphisms.  Specifically, the center of each hexagon can be a vertex and between any two vertices, an edge can be drawn with length 1. This creates the complete graph $K_7$ where any of the 7 triangles can be mapped to any of the other triangles in 6 ($3!$) different ways.  For example, the triangle formed by the red, green, and blue hexagons can be mapped to the triangle formed by the cyan, magenta, and yellow hexagons in 6 different ways.
If one wanted a game map with the same automorphism group but for 14 players/teams, then a base could be placed at each vertex of the map rather than at the center of each hexagon.  However, if one wanted to play with more people while achieving even higher degrees of symmetry, then surfaces with a higher genus would be required.
Similarly, it may be fun to play with game maps which are non-orientable, closed, highly symmetric, and which have constant curvature.  In a game, perhaps the use of chirality in non-orientable spaces could be used as a sort of gimmick.

Two clarifications: (i) Does "automorphism" mean isometry? (ii) Does "the automorphism group of the surface is $G$" mean the isometry group has a subgroup isomorphic to $G$?

The answer is positive and there are several proofs, all following the proofs in the orientable case. But you probably do not have enough background to understand any of these. BTW, it is much easier to prove existence of a nonorientable surface whose automorphism group contains the given finite group. How much algebraic topology do you know?

@MoisheKohan You are correct.  I do not have enough background to understand the proofs.  I know very little algebraic topology, despite having much interest in the topic.  For your last sentence, I’m guessing you prove that for any n, there exists a nonorientable surface such that it’s automorphism group contains $S_n$.  However, it would be even more interesting if the there were nonorientable surfaces whose automorohism group was precisely $G$ for any finite group $G$, which it sounds like uou are saying is true anyways.  I will consider this question closed.

You were actually the one that told me about the orientable case.

@AndrewD.Hwang i)  Yes.  ii)  No, I mean a surface whose isometry group is exactly $G$.

@MoisheKohan Final question.  Is there something akin to Hurwitz’s automorphism theorem or Hurwitz surfaces for nonorientable manifolds?  A visual representation, such as a fundamental polygon, of a highly symmetric, nonorientable surface akin to Bolza’s surface or Macbeath Surface could be useful for intuition.
